# Go: Performance Hit of Waiting for Multiple Channels

Tags: performance, go, channel

I discovered something today that threw me for a bit of a loop, and I wanted to run it by the community to see if I'm missing something, or perhaps just designing things poorly.

Use case: I have an input channel, and I want a Go routine to wait for values on that channel. If the context is canceled, exit out. Optionally, also run a callback if it's been waiting a certain amount of time for an input without receiving one.

I started with code like this:

```golang
func myRoutine(ctx context.Context, c <-chan int, callbackInterval *time.Duration, callback func() error) {
    var timeoutChan <-chan time.Time
    var timer *time.Timer
    if callbackInterval != nil {
        // If we have a callback interval set, create a timer for it
        timer = time.NewTimer(*callbackInterval)
        timeoutChan = timer.C
    } else {
        // If we don't have a callback interval set, create
        // a channel that will never provide a value.
        timeoutChan = make(<-chan time.Time, 0)
    }

    for {
        select {

        // Handle context cancellation
        case <-ctx.Done():
            return

        // Handle timeouts
        case <-timeoutChan:
            callback()

        // Handle a value in the channel
        case v, ok := <-c:
            if !ok {
                // Channel is closed, exit out
                return
            }

            // Do something with v
            fmt.Println(v)
        }

        // Reset the timeout timer, if there is one
        if timer != nil {
            if !timer.Stop() {
                // See documentation for timer.Stop() for why this is needed
                <-timer.C
            }
            // Reset the timer
            timer.Reset(*callbackInterval)
            timeoutChan = timer.C
        }
    }
}
```

This design seemed nice because there's no way (as far as I can tell) to have a conditional `case` in a `select` (I think it's possible with `reflect`, but that's usually super slow), so instead of having two different `selects` (one with the timer when a timer is needed, one without) and an `if` to select between them, I just did one `select` where the timer channel never provides a value if a timer isn't desired. Keep it DRY.

But then I started wondering about the performance impacts of this. When we're not using a timer, would it slow down the application to have this extra channel in the `select` that never gets a value (in place of the timer channel)?

So, I decided to do some testing to compare.

```golang
package main

import (
    "context"
    "fmt"
    "reflect"
    "time"
)

func prepareChan() chan int {
    var count int = 10000000

    c := make(chan int, count)

    for i := 0; i < count; i++ {
        c <- i
    }
    close(c)
    return c
}

func oneChan() int64 {
    c := prepareChan()

    foundVal := true
    start := time.Now()
    for {
        select {
        case _, foundVal = <-c:
            break
        }
        if !foundVal {
            break
        }
    }
    ms := time.Since(start).Milliseconds()
    fmt.Printf("1 Chan - Standard: %dms\n", ms)
    return ms
}

func twoChan() int64 {
    c := prepareChan()

    neverchan1 := make(chan struct{}, 0)

    foundVal := true
    start := time.Now()
    for {
        select {
        case _, foundVal = <-c:
            break
        case <-neverchan1:
            break
        }
        if !foundVal {
            break
        }
    }
    ms := time.Since(start).Milliseconds()
    fmt.Printf("2 Chan - Standard: %dms\n", ms)
    return ms
}

func threeChan() int64 {
    c := prepareChan()

    neverchan1 := make(chan struct{}, 0)
    neverchan2 := make(chan struct{}, 0)

    foundVal := true
    start := time.Now()
    for {
        select {
        case _, foundVal = <-c:
            break
        case <-neverchan1:
            break
        case <-neverchan2:
            break
        }
        if !foundVal {
            break
        }
    }
    ms := time.Since(start).Milliseconds()
    fmt.Printf("3 Chan - Standard: %dms\n", ms)
    return ms
}

func fourChan() int64 {
    c := prepareChan()

    neverchan1 := make(chan struct{}, 0)
    neverchan2 := make(chan struct{}, 0)
    neverchan3 := make(chan struct{}, 0)

    foundVal := true
    start := time.Now()
    for {
        select {
        case _, foundVal = <-c:
            break
        case <-neverchan1:
            break
        case <-neverchan2:
            break
        case <-neverchan3:
            break
        }
        if !foundVal {
            break
        }
    }
    ms := time.Since(start).Milliseconds()
    fmt.Printf("4 Chan - Standard: %dms\n", ms)
    return ms
}

func oneChanReflect() int64 {
    c := reflect.ValueOf(prepareChan())

    branches := []reflect.SelectCase{
        {Dir: reflect.SelectRecv, Chan: c, Send: reflect.Value{}},
    }

    start := time.Now()
    for {
        _, _, recvOK := reflect.Select(branches)
        if !recvOK {
            break
        }
    }
    ms := time.Since(start).Milliseconds()
    fmt.Printf("1 Chan - Reflect: %dms\n", ms)
    return ms
}

func twoChanReflect() int64 {
    c := reflect.ValueOf(prepareChan())
    neverchan1 := reflect.ValueOf(make(chan struct{}, 0))

    branches := []reflect.SelectCase{
        {Dir: reflect.SelectRecv, Chan: c, Send: reflect.Value{}},
        {Dir: reflect.SelectRecv, Chan: neverchan1, Send: reflect.Value{}},
    }

    start := time.Now()
    for {
        _, _, recvOK := reflect.Select(branches)
        if !recvOK {
            break
        }
    }
    ms := time.Since(start).Milliseconds()
    fmt.Printf("2 Chan - Reflect: %dms\n", ms)
    return ms
}

func threeChanReflect() int64 {
    c := reflect.ValueOf(prepareChan())
    neverchan1 := reflect.ValueOf(make(chan struct{}, 0))
    neverchan2 := reflect.ValueOf(make(chan struct{}, 0))

    branches := []reflect.SelectCase{
        {Dir: reflect.SelectRecv, Chan: c, Send: reflect.Value{}},
        {Dir: reflect.SelectRecv, Chan: neverchan1, Send: reflect.Value{}},
        {Dir: reflect.SelectRecv, Chan: neverchan2, Send: reflect.Value{}},
    }

    start := time.Now()
    for {
        _, _, recvOK := reflect.Select(branches)
        if !recvOK {
            break
        }
    }
    ms := time.Since(start).Milliseconds()
    fmt.Printf("3 Chan - Reflect: %dms\n", ms)
    return ms
}

func fourChanReflect() int64 {
    c := reflect.ValueOf(prepareChan())
    neverchan1 := reflect.ValueOf(make(chan struct{}, 0))
    neverchan2 := reflect.ValueOf(make(chan struct{}, 0))
    neverchan3 := reflect.ValueOf(make(chan struct{}, 0))

    branches := []reflect.SelectCase{
        {Dir: reflect.SelectRecv, Chan: c, Send: reflect.Value{}},
        {Dir: reflect.SelectRecv, Chan: neverchan1, Send: reflect.Value{}},
        {Dir: reflect.SelectRecv, Chan: neverchan2, Send: reflect.Value{}},
        {Dir: reflect.SelectRecv, Chan: neverchan3, Send: reflect.Value{}},
    }

    start := time.Now()
    for {
        _, _, recvOK := reflect.Select(branches)
        if !recvOK {
            break
        }
    }
    ms := time.Since(start).Milliseconds()
    fmt.Printf("4 Chan - Reflect: %dms\n", ms)
    return ms
}

func main() {
    oneChan()
    oneChanReflect()
    twoChan()
    twoChanReflect()
    threeChan()
    threeChanReflect()
    fourChan()
    fourChanReflect()
}
```

And the results:

```
1 Chan - Standard: 169ms
1 Chan - Reflect: 1017ms
2 Chan - Standard: 460ms
2 Chan - Reflect: 1593ms
3 Chan - Standard: 682ms
3 Chan - Reflect: 2041ms
4 Chan - Standard: 950ms
4 Chan - Reflect: 2423ms
```

It scales linearly with the number of channels. In hindsight, I suppose this makes sense, as it must be doing a fast loop to poll each channel to see if it has a value? As expected, using `reflect` is far slower.

In any case, my questions are:

1. Does this result surprise anyone else? I would have expected it would use a interrupt-based design that would allow it to maintain the same performance regardless of the number of channels in the `select`, as it wouldn't need to poll each channel.
2. Given the original problem that I was trying to solve (an "optional" case in a `select`), what would be the best/preferred design? Is the answer just to have two different `select`s, one with the timer and one without? That gets awfully messy when I have 2 or 3 conditional/optional timers for various things.

**EDIT:**
@Brits suggested using a nil channel for "never returning a value" instead of an initialized channel, i.e. using `var neverchan1 chan struct{}` instead of `neverchan1 := make(chan struct{}, 0)`. Here are the new performance results:

```
1 Chan - Standard: 221ms
1 Chan - Reflect: 1639ms
2 Chan - Standard: 362ms
2 Chan - Reflect: 2544ms
3 Chan - Standard: 376ms
3 Chan - Reflect: 3359ms
4 Chan - Standard: 394ms
4 Chan - Reflect: 4123ms
```

There's still an effect, most noticeably from one channel in the `select` to two, but after the second one the performance impact is much smaller than with an initialized channel.

Still wondering if this is the best possible solution though...

Comment: Checking more conditions takes more time, then you're multiplying that times `10000000`.

Comment: Of course, it takes more time to check more conditions. But I would have expected it to use an interrupt-based design that removes the need for "checking conditions" in the first place.

Comment: (FYI, you are aware that the `break` statements are not breaking out of anything because they are in a switch block? Just making sure you are executing what you think you are executing)

Comment: An alternative to using `select` with a `channel` that "channel never provides a value" is to use a `nil` channel (["never ready for communication"](https://go.dev/ref/spec#Channel_types)) Replacing `neverchan1 := make(chan struct{}, 0)` with `var neverchan1 chan struct{}` (or `neverchan1 := chan struct{}(nil)`) significantly increases performance in my tests.

Comment: @JimB Yeah, I just do it because I've written C++ all of my life and now it's a habit. If I break that habit for Go, I'll be screwed on the days I'm writing C++ again :)

Comment: @Brits Damn, I never thought to try a nil value, I just assumed it would panic if I tried to get an output from a nil channel. But yeah, it drastically improves performance. There's still an effect, but it's much smaller (see my edit in the OP for the performance numbers).

Comment: "break" statements aren't the thing that gets me when switching languages (C, C++, Go)... :-)

Comment: @Brits If you want to turn your comment into an answer, I'll accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per the comments an alternative to using `select` with a channel that "channel never provides a value" is to use a `nil` channel (["never ready for communication"](https://go.dev/ref/spec#Channel_types)). Replacing `neverchan1 := make(chan struct{}, 0)` with `var neverchan1 chan struct{}` (or `neverchan1 := chan struct{}(nil)`) as per the following example:

```
func twoChan() int64 {
    c := prepareChan()

    var neverchan1 chan struct{} // was neverchan1 := make(chan struct{}, 0)

    foundVal := true
    start := time.Now()
    for {
        select {
        case _, foundVal = <-c:
            break
        case <-neverchan1:
            break
        }
        if !foundVal {
            break
        }
    }
    ms := time.Since(start).Milliseconds()
    fmt.Printf("2 Chan - Standard: %dms\n", ms)
    return ms
}
```

This significantly narrows the gap (using 4 channel version as the difference is greater - my machine is a bit slower than yours):

```
4 Chan - Standard: 1281ms
4 Chan - Nil: 394ms
```

> is the best possible solution

No; but that would probably involve some assembler! There are a number things you could do that *may* improve on this ([here](https://go.dev/play/p/QkxRx7ZHYnD) are a few very rough examples); however their effectiveness is going to depend on a range of factors (real life vs contrived test case performance often differs significantly).

At this point I would be asking "what impact is optimising this function going to have on the overall application?"; unless saving a few `ns` will make a material difference (i.e. improve profit!) I'd suggest stopping at this point until you:

- Have confirmed that there is an issue to address
- Can [profile](https://go.dev/blog/pprof) the code in a realistic scenario (also, in general, I feel that ["readability beats speed"](https://bitfieldconsulting.com/golang/slower)).